# Transforming prior distribution in inference for binomial N parameter

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, hierarchical-bayesian

I'm struggling with question 6 in the Exercises to Chapter 3 (page 80) of Bayesian Data Analysis by Andrew Gelman.

[http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/BDA3.pdf](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/book/BDA3.pdf)

We have data Y modeled as independent binomial data, with both $N$ and $θ$ unknown, as per Raftery's 1988 paper "Inference for the binomial N parameter: A hierarchical Bayes approach".

$Y∼Bin(N,θ)$ and

$N∼Poisson(μ)$, where $λ=μθ$

The (noninformative) prior distribution of $λ,θ$ is $p(λ,θ) \propto λ^{-1}$

The question 6(a) asks you to **transform to determine $p(N,θ)$.**

It's similar to the following question, but I haven't been able to use that to get to the answer.

[Bayesian Aproach: Infering the N and $\theta$ values from a binomial distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77575/bayesian-aproach-infering-the-n-and-theta-values-from-a-binomial-distributio)

Comment: I might start by looking for an expression for the distribution of $\mu, \theta$ i.e. the prior $p(\mu, \theta)$ as a change of variable, remembering $\theta \in [0,1]$

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I got (I'm not very sure about it).
I think in that exercise, $N$ is supposed to follow a Poisson distribution with *random* expectation $\mu$. The (improper) joint distribution of $\mu, \theta$ is defined on the transformation $(\lambda  = \mu \theta, \theta)$ by
$$p(\mu, \lambda) \propto 1/\lambda .$$
In order to get the joint distribution of $(\mu, \theta)$ you would need to use the fact that
$$p(\mu, \theta) = p(\lambda, \theta) \mid\det\frac{\partial(\lambda, \theta)}{\partial(\mu, \theta)}\mid$$

Here, $\mid\det\frac{\partial(\lambda, \theta)}{\partial(\mu, \theta)}\mid = \theta$ such that the improper distribution of $(\mu, \theta)$ is $p(\mu, \theta) \propto 1 / \mu$ so the prior is :
$$\begin{array}{lcl}
p(\mu) &\propto & 1 / \mu\\
N & \sim & \mathcal{P}(\mu) \\
\theta & \sim & \mathcal{U}([0, 1])
\end{array}$$