Jeffreys' prior for a discrete parameter space
The following question speaks about binomial distribution with known probability $p$, but unknown number of trials $n$.
Binomial confidence interval over the number of trials
Trying to think of how a Bayesian interval would be constructed for such a case I passed first at the stage to thinking about the Jeffreys prior. However, for a discrete parameter space this is not defined because the derivative does not exist.
Are there approaches to find a prior according to the same ideas? Of course, the property of invariance of the distribution under coordinate transformations is obsolete since probability mass functions don't transform like probability density functions. Is that the only property/motivation for Jeffreys prior, or are there other properties that can be applied to probability mass functions as well?

Possibly we could try some continuous analogue of a binomial distribution? That might lead to different options, but I am sure there are  some more simple/desired cases among them.

The binomial distribution has a relationship between variance and expectation like $Var[X] = (1-p) E[X]$. Are there known distributions that match that? Or otherwise we could maybe model it as a normal distribution $X \sim N(np,np(1-p))$ and for that case a Jeffreys prior should exist and might be computed.

Relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/500781/transforming-prior-distribution-in-inference-for-binomial-n-parameter, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/275600/jeffreys-prior-for-binomial-likelihood, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113851/bayesian-estimation-of-n-of-a-binomial-distribution, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/588863/why-not-use-the-same-distribution-for-the-prior-in-bayesian-statistics, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/502124/numbers-of-draws-on-a-modified-bernouilli-process/521043#521043 and search for more ...

Possibly another approach could be to have a multistage model with a continuous parameter that models a discrete distribution from which the parameter $n$ is obtained, and we let the variance of that distribution approach zero. Should different of such multistage models lead to the same result (same prior).

Number of trials to get a known count of successes (the observed data) would be negative binomial.

@Glen_b That might indeed be a conjugate prior. But the count of successes is not known, it is observed. So if we use the negative binomial as prior, then what count of successes to use?

If it is observed, you do know what it was. Or you can come at it from the relationship between the binomial and the negative binomial

@Glen_b but a prior is independent from the observation. I can see how the likelihood has the shape of a negative binomial distribution for a single observation, but for multiple observations I am not sure what it is and it deviates from a negative binomial (maybe the negative binomial isn't conjugate after all).

Literature on bayesian feature selection might contain some recipes - since they are concerned with inherently discrete parameters, like the number of features in a model.

One approach can be to approximate binomial distribution with a normal distribution
$$X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu=\theta,\sigma^2=q\theta)$$ where $q = (1-p)$ is fixed and $\theta = np$ is unknown and we search a Jeffreys prior for it.
The Jeffreys prior is proportional to the square root of the Fisher information matrix
$$\mathcal{I}(\theta) = E\left[\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \log f(x;\theta)\right)^2\right]  $$
and
$$\begin{array}{}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \log f(x;\theta) &=& \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \left(-\log(2\pi q\theta)-\frac{(x-\theta)^2}{2q\theta} \right) \\
&=& - \frac{1}{\theta} + \frac{x^2/\theta^2-1}{2q} 
\end{array}$$
and using
$$E[x^2] = (\theta^2+q \theta)$$
$$E[x^4] = \theta^4 + 6 q\theta^3 + 3q^2 \theta^2$$
we get
$$\begin{array}{}
E\left[\left(- \frac{1}{\theta} + \frac{x^2/\theta^2-1}{2q} \right)^2\right]& = &E\left[ \frac{1}{\theta^2} - \frac{x^2/\theta^3-1/\theta}{q} +  \frac{x^4/\theta^4-2x^2/\theta^2 + 1}{4q^2} \right]\\
&=&  \frac{1}{q \theta }+\frac{3}{4\theta^2} 
\end{array} $$
Then a prior could be
$$p(\theta) \propto \sqrt{\frac{1}{q \theta }+\frac{3}{4\theta^2} } $$

I thought that these calculations were gonna give some insight, but I am not so sure what it means. For example with $q=1$ I would have expected to get a similar result as the Jeffreys prior for the Poisson distribution, but it isn't.
